# klist returns no tickets when using "pam_krb5.so try_first_pass"

Tags: linux, centos7, kerberos, pam, sssd

We have

```
auth        optional      pam_krb5.so try_first_pass
```

in

```
/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac
```

and

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
```

however when I do a klist after successful login, I get

```
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/nnnnn)
```

What could be the reason for this?

**auth and session stack:**

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=12 unlock_time=3600
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        optional      pam_krb5.so try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so



session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Comment: Please show the entire auth stack. I also recommend showing session. Some krb5 implementations might not call `pam_setcred()` within the auth stack.

Comment: @AndrewB, i added the auth and the session stack. please advise.

Comment: 1) Are you authenticating with a password when you connect to this system? 2) Are you sure that pam_krb5 was the successful PAM module? There are modules before and after pam_krb5 that can succeed. I suspect that it is *not* succeeding, because it is currently set to `optional`, which implies that successful authentication would be ignored. (should be `sufficient`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out pam_krb5 was missing from the session stack:

```
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_krb5.so
```

adding **session     required      pam_krb5.so** fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep, that would do it. To clarify for future readers, this is entirely dependent on which implementation of `pam_krb` comes bundled with your operating system. The [Russ Allbery implementation](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/pam-krb5.html) handles this in the `auth` stack as well as the `session` stack, while others only do so in session. This tends to confuse people. It should be noted that you must *always* have it in the session stack (regardless of implementation) if you are using GSSAPI authentication, as it bypasses the auth stack. That's why I asked about login method.